# Does series converge $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^2+2 n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm solving problems on [Pauls online notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcII/SeriesCompTest/Prob8.aspx) and in solution for [exercise](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcII/SeriesCompTest/Prob8.aspx) $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^2+2 n}$ I found he used Comparison Test to get to the solution. But I got the same answer but using the Limit Comparison Test and I'm wondering if it's correct.

My work:
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^2+2 n} = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n(n+2)}$$ and when removing $2$ from numerator I got the following relation:

$$
\begin{gathered}
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^2+2 n}<\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^2} \\
\Rightarrow c=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{-\infty}}{n(n+2)} \cdot \frac{n^2}{e^{-n}}=1
\end{gathered}
$$

Witch should prove that this series converges.

Comment: $\frac{\mathbf{e}^{-n}}{n^2+2 n}\leq e^{-n}$ and $\sum e^{-n} <\infty$ by ratio test.

Comment: $\sum e^{-n}$ converges because it is a geometric series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit comparison test will only give you the conclusion that ''the series both converge or both diverge''. So far, what you just showed is
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^2+2 n}\text{ and }\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^2}$$
either both converge or both diverge.

However, you have to make sure one of these two converges to conclude the other also does. So, it is necessary to determine the series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^2}$ converges for your partial answer being completely correct.

(Also, you won't need to do that if you already know or have shown somewhere in you textbook the series converges.)